# How can I use ForwardAgent with keychain, or detect a new login?

Tags: ssh, security

My scenario:

I have `Server A` at home, and `Server B` at my parents house. I also have `Laptop A` and `Laptop B` at home. I do all sorts of strange ssh hops - I might connect `Laptop A -> Server A -> Server B`. Or `Laptop B -> Server A -> Laptop A`. Or `Server A -> Server B`

I've got keychain set up on all of these machines, and like a good security-conscious geek, I have

```
eval `keychain --clear`
```

in my `.zlogin` file.

My problem is that even though I unlock my keys on `Laptop A`, once I've  connected to `Server A` it tries to use the keychain/ssh-agent on Server A, so I have to unlock *those* keys, too. I've got `ForwardAgent` setup on all of these machines as well. What I would prefer to happen is something like this:

- Login to `Laptop A`
- Unlock `Laptop A` keys
- ssh to `Server A`
- ssh to `Server B` - using keys from `Laptop A`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question but it does give you an alternative option to consider that may help you out. I typically setup my `$HOME/.ssh/config` file like so:

```
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my-computers

# infrastructure
Host lap1
    User sam
    #PubkeyAuthentication no
    ProxyCommand ssh sam@my.dom.com nc lap1.internal.local %p
```

Then when I want to connect to my lap1.internal.local system when I'm out and about I just do an:

```
ssh lap1
```

I typically ssh-copy-id my public keys to other servers that I want to login to. Let me know if you'd like me to elaborate.